# Forced harvesting of organs in China

Tags: china

Is the Chinese government under any obligation to stop the forced harvesting of organs on prisoners that they started?

Comment: I am sure he means this...  https://www.forbes.com/sites/zakdoffman/2019/06/18/china-killing-prisoners-to-harvest-organs-for-transplant-tribunal-finds/#56c5fa8253d4

Comment: What kind of obligation? Legal? Moral? An obligation based on international law?

Comment: Skeptics.SE is probably a better fit.

Comment: @Jontia Skeptics Stack Exchange would reject this question because it doesn't mention a falsifiable claim made by a notable source and doesn't ask if that claim is true or false.

Comment: yes dolphin thats what I mean and Im talking about a legal obligation in any way

Comment: Is the question, "Is there any international requirement that would stop China from forced harvesting of organs from prisoners?"  United Nations, treaties, etc.

Comment: @Brythan Good question. If the asker here is not responding, someone else should ask this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although several human rights complaints have been filed with the UN and other international organizations, China has denied any wrongdoing.

Also, among the area populated with Uyghur Muslims (the ethnic group targeted by the organ harvesting scheme), there is a lot of security and surveillance. It is not easy to send reporters or outsiders into those areas, and impossible for them to infiltrate any surgical centers where the procedures are happening.

China, as an independent nation is not "obliged" to stop doing anything. Although a great deal of international pressure may bring focus to the issue and force China to stop. At the present moment, most international powers seem to want to avoid direct confrontation with China, so the abuse is not likely to stop anytime soon.

Answer (score 0):

Given that china has never acknowledged this practice, I am not sure how they would stop doing what they have not admitted to doing.

It would be like asking if Saudi Arabia is under any obligation to charge the crown prince for Khashoggi.

Why would they be when they have never acknowledged the crow prince or anyone was involved.

Comment: According to https://www.forbes.com/sites/zakdoffman/2019/06/18/china-killing-prisoners-to-harvest-organs-for-transplant-tribunal-finds/#2285719953d4  "[b]ack in 2014, the Chinese government claimed that the practice of harvesting organs from executed prisoners would stop," which to me sounds like an acknowledgement.

Comment: @owjburnham:  you are actually incorrect:  https://www.scmp.com/news/world/europe/article/3003508/china-stopped-harvesting-organs-executed-prisoners-2015-prove-it    They never acknowledged the practice.  they just said, they will ensure all organs will be certified as coming from volunteers.  a subtle but significant difference.

Comment: @owjburnham: Why would the harvesting of organs from executed prisoners, or people who die from any other cause, be considered a human rights violation?  The execution itself very well could be, but not harvesting usable organs seems like a violation of the human rights of those who might otherwise receive the organs.

Comment: @jamesqf: organ transplant is a huge business in China.  That is an open secret.   And that created a pretty unsettling potential for conflict of interest, vis a vis justice and human rights.

Comment: @dolphin_of_france: As I said.  The executions might well be a human rights issue.  Organ harvesting is not.